# WriteValueAsString IS converting INT to String, scala

Tags: json-deserialization, jackson-databind

I have a map as below

```
 val weightedPartitionMap : Map[Int,String] = Map(0 -> "S", 1 -> "M", 2 -> "L")
 val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
 objectMapper.registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule)
 val tryJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(weightedPartitionMap)
tryJson is  
 "{\"0\":\"S\",\"1\":\"M\",\"2":\"L\"}"

WHERE AS it Should be "{0:\"S\",1:\"M\",2:\"L\"}"
```

Is there any setting that needs to happen for it to not convert this map to string, string Please let me know